# Regular expression for version numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get such matches:

```
3.1.0
10.5.1
0.5
```

which may represent builds version numbering system.

Non-matches:

```
3.1.
```

I tried this regex:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

This gets only `0.5` but not `10.5.1`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What about this:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

Comment: That's what I wanted exactly and your old one `\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}` is good and can be put as `\d+(?:\.\d+){1,100}` as an acceptable approach.

Comment: Yours suffers the same pitfall that mine does (i.e. matches `10.5.`): http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=f9dc4e62-06db-4a53-a60a-e3291cf33c29

Comment: @Mrchief: nope, your old (with `*`) has matched trailing `.` too. While mine doesn't

Comment: What @zerkms is saying is right. it does not match `10.5.` and the like.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,6})?$
```

This will match Major.Minor and optional revision.  Major and Minor can be 1-3 digits (0-999) and Revision can be 6 digits.

Valid:
1.1
1.2.3
1.2.123456

Not valid:
1
1.2.
1.2.1234567
1.2.*
Anything with a alpha character

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?
```

Comment: 1. `(?:` 2. This will match even `10.5.` which is just incorrect

Comment: Ok it works for triple numbers but can't we guarantee that even this will be matched `1.2.3.4.5.6` as long as of format (number.number...etc) regardless of how many number/floating-point/number are there?

Comment: @zerkms: The match will only contain 10.5 but yeah, I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should make more sense:

```
^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))*$
```

Every numeric component have to start with non-zero if it's more than 1 digits.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it can be 010.5.3, so it's really not a full version system but much like it.

Comment: @LordCover Never mind.  I'd vote for zerkms' answer then.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old topic, but I found the same problem and found somewhat simpler solution so this might help someone looking for an answer.
This [`(\[0-9\]+\[\.\]?)+`](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=05fae132-d3a2-4127-898e-0d790712a841) will match these:

```
7.1.1
12.1.1.3.12.442.5463.343.44.5
9
11.1.1
11.1.1
```

additionally if someone would like to get only the numbers (alternatively to split on dot)
this will do the trick:

```
[0-9]+[\.]??
```

([regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=b980f0c7-195e-4aea-83f0-ebb2ad0d9c83))

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it thoroughly but that's it folks :-)

```
(?<major>\d+)(?<minor>:\.\d+)?(?<build>:\.\d+)?(?<revision>:\.\d+)?
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this one:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+){2}$
```

{2} ensures that versions like 10.5 not match

^ and $ will "protect" the beginning and the end of the version, preventing some situations like :

```
A10.5.1
10.5.
10.5.1A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+\.){1,3}\d+
```

Will **match** the following
Express Edition (64-bit) RTM 15.0.4223.1

```
15.0.4223.1
15.0.4
15.0
```

and **Not match** the following

```
15
15.
```