# Match a regex and reverse the matches within the target string

Tags: c#, regex, string, reverse

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618868/regular-expression-for-version-numbers) Regex `\d+(?:-\d+)+` will match this `10-3-1` and `5-0`.

Example:

```
This is 10-3-1 my string
```

After performing the matching and reversing, I want it to be like this:

```
This is 1-3-10 my string
```

Notice that 10-3-1 should become 1-3-10 and not normal string reverse which would result in 1-3-01.

Comment: Are you still looking for C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic algorithm would be:

1. Extract the match from the string. `"10-3-1"`
2. Split the match into a segments by the "-" character.
3. You now have a list of elements. `["10","3","1"]`
4. Reverse the list. `["1","3","10"]`
5. Join the elements of the array with the "-" character. `"1-3-10"`
6. Replace the match with newly joined string.

Comment: Ok seems good but what if the string contained more than one match? since this could be the case. I guess I can use GroupCollection then.

Comment: Yes, you would just perform these steps for each match found.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question was answered here is a piece of code with a slightly modified regex:

```
var text = "This is 10-3-1 and 5-2.";
var re = new Regex(@"((?<first>\d+)(?:-(?<parts>\d+))+)");
foreach (Match match in re.Matches(text))
{
    var reverseSequence = match
                            .Groups["first"]
                            .Captures.Cast<Capture>()
                            .Concat(match.Groups["parts"].Captures.Cast<Capture>())
                            .Select(x => x.Value)
                            .Reverse()
                            .ToArray();
    text = text.Replace(match.Value, string.Join("-", reverseSequence));
}
```