# Replace string between specific characters

Tags: c#, regex

I was wondering how do I use regex to replace string between two characters.

```
var oldString  = "http://localhost:61310/StringtoConvert?Id=1"
```

Expected result  = `"http://localhost:61310/ConvertedString?Id=1"`

Comment: Did you try anything? Look at any documentation for how to use regex?

Comment: Possible [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619398/match-a-regex-and-reverse-the-matches-within-the-target-string) helps

Comment: I would like to thank you all for help. I have implemented private static string ReplacePath(string url, string newPath)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);     
    return $"{uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}/{path}{uri.Query}";
} and it works

Comment: @AshishParajuli use Eser's solution, its way better than mine.  Also mark their answer as the correct one

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex or string operations, use UriBuilder class.

```
var oldString = "http://localhost:61310/StringtoConvert?Id=1";
var newuri = new UriBuilder(new Uri(oldString));
newuri.Path = "ConvertedString";
var result = newuri.ToString();
```

Comment: I didn't even know that class existed haha, this answer beats mine!

Comment: I made a fork of my fiddle with your code if you want to include it in your answer, see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qPs93r)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regex.Replace(string, string, string)`. So, if you want to replace a substring between a `/` and a `?`, you can use

```
string result = Regex.Replace(oldString, "(?<=\/)[^\?]*(?=\?)", "ConvertedString");
```

`?<=` is a lookbehind, `\/` escapes the slash character, `[^\?]*` matches any characters not a ? any number of times, `?=` is a lookahead, and `\?` escapes the question mark character.

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(oldString, "(http\:\/\/localhost\:61310\/)(\w+)(\?Id\=1)", "$1ConvertedString$3");`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Regex, you can use the `System.Uri` class then concatenate or interpolate your new value:

```
private static string ReplacePath(string url, string newPath)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);     
    return $"{uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}/{newPath}{uri.Query}";
}
```

Calling this method with your url, and the new path (ie "ConvertedString") will result in the output: `"http://localhost:61310/ConvertedString?Id=1"`

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UX43xg).

**EDIT**

@Eser's answer is way better than mine.  Did not know that class existed. Mark their answer as the right one **not mine**.

Comment: Thanks maccettura. I like you approach.