# Regular expression for version and software name

Tags: python, regex

I have:

```
TYPO3 4.2 is installed on machine ...
Winamp is installed on machine ...
Winrar 3.20 is installed on machine ...
```

How can i make a regular expression for separating the software package name in a sentence. Above there is an example for a software\version, but the sentence is not always the same, and also there are times where the version is not displayed. Any hints how can the re be? I found this topic but it is just for version: [Regular expression for version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618868/regular-expression-for-version-numbers)

As i read some comments i forgot to put some stuff like:

- Software version hasn't got a standard form, but it is dot separated
- The name of the software is before the version
- It could happen that i have the software name, but is there a way to find it's version in some text that hasn't got the same structure as the sentences mention above?
- The above sentence is not standard !

Comment: The only way people can help you write a regex is if you give them a wide variety of the data you need to match.  Show more data.

Comment: if the format is always <SOMETHING> is <whatever> you can first match everything from beginning of line, till "is" and than examine that chunk for Name, Name + version or whatever.

Comment: Judging by your examples you expect the regular expression to return the first token on the line and the second token if all its characters are from [0-9.].  Is that correct ?

Comment: Version numbers are not standardized, so this will be quite hard, unless you have specific requirements to them.

Comment: Is the program name always one word, or is it possible to be multiple words? Do your sentences always start with 'is', or is every word possible, or a limited set of words? If the program name can be multiple words, has no version number and the sentence can be every imaginable word, than it isn't possible. In all the other cases it is.

Answer (score 6):

For the data you've shown:

```
version = sentence.partition(" is installed on")[0]
```

No regex needed, just take everything before " is installed on".

Comment: as i said it is not a standard sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can use the following heuristics:

1. "is installed" is a marker where the software name and version ends
2. The version does not contain spaces and only digits or dots
3. Everything before the version is the name of the software

We can then use something like the following:

```
(.*?) ([\d.]+ )?is installed
```

The first group is the software name, the second the version (if present).

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $strings = 'TYPO3 4.2 is installed on machine ...','Winamp is installed on machine ...', 'Winrar 3.20 is installed on machine ...'
PS> $strings | %{ $null = $_ -match '(.*?) ([\d.]+ )?is installed'; "Software: " + $Matches[1] + ", version: " + $Matches[2] }
Software: TYPO3, version: 4.2
Software: Winamp, version:
Software: Winrar, version: 3.20
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info about the data (see my comment)

If the program name is always one word:
`m = re.search(r'(?P<name>\S+?) (?P<version>([\d.]+ )?)', text)`

If the sentence starts with the word 'is' or 'installed':
`m = re.search(r'(?P<name>(\S\s)+?)(?P<version>([\d.]+ )?)(is|installed)', text)`

```
name = m.group('name').strip()
version = m.group('version').strip()
```